# JSON API response from endpoint retrieve value and decode

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

The endpoint send a

**Response**

```
WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
(
[response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
(
[body] => {“status”:”success”,”result”:”112″,”code”:200}
```

I was trying to get the `“result:”112”`

Is there a way I can retrieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: what've your tryed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_requests_response/

Assuming the response you are getting (WP_HTTP_Requests_Response) is stored in a variable called $response you should do:

```
$response_data = json_decode($response->get_response_object()->body);
$result = $response_data->result; // this is the result you want
```

Comment: Hello,

The response I'm getting is thru email using the plugin 3rd-party-integration. I am not sure how to put that on a variable since I'm not sure where to get it since it's a debug notification thru email. 

Sorry.

Thanks!